# How to use ClaimsPrincipial

Tags: c#, authentication, google-cloud-platform, authorize-attribute

I have a web application that works correctly on my local machine from the VS2017 and the same application is working not correctly from the Google Cloud platform.
In my local machine, I have secure site pages [Authorize]

This is a picture in local computer

This picture after deploy to "Cloud Google Platform" -  App Engine Flex

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;



    public static ApplicationUser currentUser = new ApplicationUser();
    public static ApplicationRole currentRole = new ApplicationRole();

    private CurrentUser currentUserST;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;

        currentUserST = CurrentUser.Instance;
        if  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUserST.UserName) )
            _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Old user from Cookie - Empty 
####AAAAA");
        else
            _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Old user from Cookie- " + 
currentUserST.UserName + " ####AAAAA");
    }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        currentUser = new ApplicationUser();           
        currentRole = new ApplicationRole();
        currentUserST.UserName = string.Empty;
        _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Login Page Hit - User Empty ! 
####AAAAA");
        _logger.LogTrace("####AAAAA Before check ModelState ####AAAAA");
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("JennyTokar", "Abcd_123", false, 
lockoutOnFailure: false);

_userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser).Result.Single();

ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]     
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string 
returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        // for debug and print
        _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Before check modelState 
####AAAAA");
        _logger.LogTrace("####AAAAA Before check ModelState ####AAAAA");

        _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Print User Name from login- " + 
model.UserName + " ####AAAAA ");
        _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA Print Password from login- " + 
model.Password + " ####AAAAA ");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set 
lockoutOnFailure: true
            //var result = await 
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, 
model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA  ModelState IsValid Entry user 
name - " + model.UserName);
            var result = await 
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, 
model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                // for debug and print
                currentUser = await 
_userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                currentRole.Name = 
_userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser).Result.Single();

                currentRole = _roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == 
currentRole.Name);
                currentRole.Id = _roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == 
currentRole.Name).Id;

                currentUserST.UserName = model.UserName;
                currentUserST.RoleName = currentRole.Name;
                _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA  User logged in. from DB - 
" + currentUserST.UserName + " Role " + currentUserST.RoleName);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA - RequiresTwoFactor");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { 
returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA - IsLockedOut");
                _logger.LogWarning("####AAAAA - User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
            _logger.LogInformation("####AAAAA - Invalid login attempt.");
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login 
attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
    }
}
```

After login does not work correctly.
in _LoginPartial.cshtml not present User
if Application run in Cloud Google App Engine flex.
Help me please .

Comment: Can you give more information than "does not work correctly"?